# getting used to my new job

Tags: phrases, idioms, business-language, synonyms

Are there good phrases to sound like a native speaker when you want to say you are getting used to your new job?

> A: How's your new job?
>
> B: _________________

Comment: *I'm still getting the hang of it.* Or *I'm Still learning the ropes.*

Comment: So far so good, is a common non specific way to say that things are going well.

Comment: I'm *growing accustomed* to my job. I'm *becoming acclimated* to the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/to-become-familiar-with-a-new-situation-or-way-of-living)

**settle into**

*to become familiar with a new way of life, place, or job, or to make someone do this*

**adjust**

*to get used to a new situation by changing your ideas or the way you do things*

**grow into**

*if you grow into a situation or activity, you gradually start knowing what to do because you have more experience*

**slot in**

*to fit well with a group of people or a way of life*

**acclimate**

American: *to gradually become more comfortable in a new place, especially where physical conditions are very different*

**accustom yourself to something**

formal: *to gradually start to feel that something is normal or natural*

**get to know**

*to start to be familiar with someone or something*

**settle in**

*to become familiar with a new way of life, place, or job, or to make someone do this;
to make yourself comfortable in a place because you are going to stay there for a long time*

**get into the swing (of something)**

*to become used to a new situation and to feel confident that you can deal with it*